# Blockquote starting with slash does not break line

Tags: bug

I used the blockquote feature to show files content on my post [Same encryption Java code outputs undecryptable content in SAP PI but decryptable in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509748/same-encryption-java-code-outputs-undecryptable-content-in-sap-pi-but-decryptabl).

One of the file is a public key. I noticed that each quoted line starting with a "/" just continues inline with the previous instead of starting a new line.

So, this short 3 lines extract

```
spZPoJDDoiM7oYZRW+ftH2EpcM7i16+4
/7fckKbAj030Nck0BjGZ//////////8A
7slmH2EEMd1WkgNMBawq2W9gEAkqgc8o
```

is actually rendered as 2 lines when I quote it:

> spZPoJDDoiM7oYZRW+ftH2EpcM7i16+4
>   /7fckKbAj030Nck0BjGZ//////////8A
>   7slmH2EEMd1WkgNMBawq2W9gEAkqgc8o

even if the post code looks like this:

```
> spZPoJDDoiM7oYZRW+ftH2EpcM7i16+4
> /7fckKbAj030Nck0BjGZ//////////8A
> 7slmH2EEMd1WkgNMBawq2W9gEAkqgc8o
```

Feel free to try editing this one to see by yourself.

Comment: Do you mean a blockquote? A comment is something else entirely. I'm seeing three lines, can you include a screenshot of what you're seeing that's not correct? What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: I do mean blockquote. I've edited the post to fix that. Also, I've made the lines shorter in the example so now you can see only the two lines instead of three.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't limited to blockquotes that start with a slash.

For example:

```
> Line 1
> Line 2
> Line 3
```

Becomes

> Line 1
>   Line 2
>   Line 3

You need the trailing two spaces for it to be on separate lines, like this (with `␣` replaced with an actual space):

```
> Line 1␣␣
> Line 2␣␣
> Line 3
```

Becomes

> Line 1
>   Line 2
>   Line 3

Comment: I've added the trailing two spaces before and after the `>` and neither works.

Comment: @Nagev: By trailing spaces, I mean at the end of the line.  I'll edit my answer to show what I mean.